# Using Beacons to synchronise an Android app and a BLE in the background

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I am new to BLE Beacons.

I have a BLE device that needs to be updated every once in a while when new data is available in my mobile app and vice-versa - when the BLE did something the app should know about.

In other words, the BLE device needs to be "synchronized" with the mobile app.

If the user opens the app, the BLE is synchronizing and everything is nice and shiny.

But I want this synchronization to work in the background, even if the user didn't open the app for 1, 2 days or even weeks so the next time the app is opened there will already be fresh data from the BLE device inside the app, and vice versa - the app will update the BLE for events that should happen even if the user didn't open the app (Like command the BLE to flash colors in 10 minutes).

I tried using the Android Bluetooth Library with RegionBootstrap, but I am confused about if Monitoring is even the way to go in my scenario.

This is the code inside my custom Application onCreate():

```
mBeaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(IBEACON_PARSER_LAYOUT));
mBeaconManager.setRegionStatePersistenceEnabled(false);
mBeaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(10000l);
mBeaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(10000l);
mBeaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1100l);
mBeaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(1100l);

region = new Region(getPackageName(),Identifier.parse(MY_BLE_BEACON_UID), null, null);
mRegionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);
```

This is my triggering events:

```
@Override
public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
  Log.e(TAG, "didEnterRegion: ");
  synchronizeBleWithTheApp();
  playSoundEnterRegion();
}

@Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
    Log.e(TAG, "didExitRegion: ");
    playSoundExitRegion();
}

private void synchronizeBleWithTheApp() {
// 1) Check if there is any new data the BLE is interested in, if yes the app should push it to the BLE in the background.

// 2) Check if there is any new data in the BLE the app is interested in, if yes fetch it from the BLE in the background.

}
```

My questions are:

1) Should I even use monitoring in my case? I mean, I want to keep trying to synchronize even if the device is still in the region every X minutes. Does the RegionBootstrap suits in this case?

Right now, the didEnterRegion is triggered once and after 30~ seconds the onExitRegion is triggered, even though the BLE beacon is transmitting which is confusing for me.

2)if synchronizeBleWithTheApp() which is inside the custom Application class uses code in an Activity MainActivity class, does it mean I need the app to open that MainActivity? can I still trigger the synchronization in the background?

Comment: If you're planning to run your app in background then you must implement foreground service and move your all logic from activity to either service level or App level. If you can't do this then you're app never work in Android OS >= 8.0 due to background limits

Comment: @MD
Do you write this in response to Question 2 right?

Comment: Yes. Does this makes sense to you ?

Comment: It makes sense, yes, I think as the Activity is dead yet the services/app components are still running.

But, why in versions less than Android 8 I can implement the synchronization logic in my Activity?

Comment: Long running service should work in android OS >= 8.0. You can @david answer for more details.

Comment: Prior to Android 8, there was no time limit on apps to stay running in the background, and started activities stay active indefinitely as long as sufficient memory is available.  With Android 8+ this is no longer true.  Apps including activities are killed after approx. 10 min in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few points:

1. If you want to get updates even when the beacon stays present, you must use ranging APIs in addition to RegionBootstrap.  Start ranging by calling `startRangingBeaconsInRegion(...)` in the `didDetermineStateForRegion` callback.
2. You should not put any background code in an Activity class as Android may kill the Activity if not visible.  The simplest place to put this code is in the custom Application class where you use RegionBootastrap (or in a custom class that is initialized and accessed from the custom Application class).

You also likely to need a foreground service to keep your app running more than 10 minutes in the background on Android 8+.  The library makes it easy to add this without programming a foreground service of your own.  See the library docs here: https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/foreground-service.html

If you see detections stop in the background after a period of time on Android 7+ (causing a region exit event), you may need to add code to force long period background scanning: https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/pull/529

Finally, be careful of custom app killers on Chinese OEMs which may make it impossible to satisfy your requirements on phones made by these manufacturers.  See here: http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2019/04/30/the-rise-of-the-nasty-forks

Comment: Thank you!!!
Just a few clarifications please:

1. I use Monitoring just once using BeaconBootstrap. This is used to know when the BLE is in the Region, so I can start a continuous ranging process - which is where the actual synchronization occurs?

2. Ranging will allow me to trigger synchronization (every X seconds/minutes or even distance), So Monitoring didn't suit as it is more logical only for Entering/Exiting regions?

3. Putting all the code that the ranging triggers either in the custom Application class or some Service - this is just so it can run because the app is killed?

Comment: You need to put the code in a custom Application class for two reasons (1) so that if the Activity is never launched, the code executes -- this is the case where the library relaunches your app into the background on beacon detection.  (2) in case the activity disappears and gets garbage collected while other parts of the app are still running.